# Java reg-ex to replace double quote inside double quote

Tags: java, regex, double, str-replace

Input string is: `"outer string "inside a quote" "`
and output should be: `"outer string inside a quote "`

Please suggest any regular expression to find the inner double quote and replace with space using Java.

Comment: That doesn't look like a regular language.

Comment: Sometimes I think, there should open be a separate Stackexchange only for regex questions..

Comment: Are the outer quotes representing that it IS a string, or are they PART of the string? In other words, `yourString.charAt(0)` is `"` or `o`?

Comment: Is there anyway to differentiate between the start of a new quote and the end of the previous one?  i.e. how do you know "inside a quote" is an inner quote, rather than there just being two separate quotes (the last one being just " ") and a bit in the middle with no quote at all?

Comment: I am having string which contains quote in side a quote so we want to replace inner quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is only one level of nesting and only one inner-quote inside outer quotes, the following should work:

```
str.replaceAll("\"(\\b[^\"]+)?\"\\b([^\"]+)\\b\"([^\"]+\\b)?\"","\"$1$2$3\"");
```

It tries to detect open vs. closing quotes by word boundaries. To allow whitespaces between the outer and inner quotes (instead of a word), and even nothing in the inner quotes, use this:

```
str.replaceAll("\"(\\b[^\"]+|\\s+)?\"(\\b[^\"]+\\b)?\"([^\"]+\\b|\\s+)?\"","\"$1$2$3\"");
```

Comment: it is not working with my actual string, i am using Java as my programming language so consider while creating the solution.

Comment: OK, that was a problem with the format. I had expected `"outer "innner""` (or `"outer "innner" outer"`), without the whitespace. The new regex does work with that. (None of them tested in Java, but I'm sure they work as intended)

Comment: Please don't edit my answer, edit your question :-) A list of test cases and expected results would be great!

Comment: OK, fixed method name and matching groups in second regex. According to [this tester](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), it works now.

Comment: thank you very much its working fine.. this is what i was looking from last 1 week but did not find it on any forum or any blog great skill.

Answer (score 2):

You can try it this way, without regex and in **one iteration**:

```
/*
 * I assume that if after quote ther is character like "a then it is
 * beggining of cite. Rest quotes are closing ones.
 */
public static String removeInnerQuotes(String data) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int quoteCounter = 0;
    char[] array = data.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == '"') {
            if (i + 1 < array.length
                    && (
                            (array[i + 1] >= 'a' && array[i + 1] <= 'z') 
                        || 
                            (array[i + 1] >= 'A' && array[i + 1] <= 'Z')
                        )
                ){
                quoteCounter++;
                if (quoteCounter == 1)
                    sb.append('"');
            }
            else{
                quoteCounter--;
                if (quoteCounter == 0)
                    sb.append('"');
            }

        } else
            sb.append(array[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "\"outer string \"inside a quote\" abc\" something outside quote, and again \"outer string \"inside a quote\" def \"";
    System.out.println(removeInnerQuotes(data));
}
```

output:

`"outer string inside a quote abc" something outside quote, and again "outer string inside a quote def "`

Comment: i am not sure which text will appear after the quote. i think this solution will not work for 100gb file where i am reading file line by line and each line and then validating data before transfer this data to SQL table. it is all in ETL tool.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for this case, a regex solution, if available *might* be slightly convoluted to be maintainable.

What you could do is have something like so:

```
String str = "outer string "inside a quote" ";
String newStr = "\"" + str.replaceAll("\"","") + "\";
```

The code above will remove all the quotation marks and add one at the beginning and end of the string.

EDIT:

I have come up with this, it is a bit convoluted but it does seem to work:

```
String str = "sdsadsaasdasdsadas\"sadsad\"the is sparta\"asdsadsa\"sdassa";
String newStr = str.replaceAll("(\".*?)\"(.*?)\"(.*?\")", "$1$2$3");
System.out.println(newStr);
```

It yields:

`sdsadsaasdasdsadas"sadsadthe is spartaasdsadsa"sdassa`

The regex above basically splits the text into 3 sections, the part prior to the first set of quotes, the set in between the inner quotations and the section after the inner quotations. It then rebuilds the string.

EDIT:

I used this code to read the string from file (note the string in this case was a 1 liner)

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (input.hasNextLine())
{
    sb.append(input.nextLine().trim()).append(" ");
}
input.close();
String str = sb.toString().trim();
String newStr = str.replaceAll("(\".*?)\"(.*?)\"(.*?\")", "$1$2$3");
System.out.println(newStr);
```

It yielded:

> "outer string inside a quote "

Comment: as i said it is a part of long string like below so above pattern will not work.             eg. sdsadsaasdasdsadas"sadsad"sadsada"asdsadsa"sdassa

Comment: @user1551515: I have updated my answer. It should work like so. However, I would advise against such an implementation since it is basically slightly convuluted.

Comment: i have tested updated answer it is working with example string but not with actual string from file. i am looking a solution that will replace all the quote which is present in outer quote. wherever it is, even i don`t know where will be the quote present.

Comment: @user1551515: I can't really say what it wrong... maybe you are using a different encoding, maybe you need to set the `MULTILINE` regex option, maybe you need to do something else.

Comment: can it be independent of encoding ? we are receiving files in various formats and various location form globe. so it may contain any type of encoded data.

Comment: @user1551515: It could quite possibly be. For instance, a character which you might be treating as a `"` might in fact be `“`, which is something that the regex above will not solve. I would recommend manually going through the a file or two that are failing and try to take it from there.

Comment: this is the actual string: 439.00  01/28/2012  65  39284   7218063470  "xyz string"" with pqr string"  78.00   0000505585  my test string  2.06    history be  29.00

Comment: @user1551515: I have made an edit to my answer. If this does not solve the problem then I would recommend you ask a new question.

Comment: @user1551515: The string you are trying is not the same as the one you have posted. The one you are trying has quotes with no text between them, which is **not** the same as the example you have posted. I have modified the regular expression used and managed to get rid of the inner quotes.

Comment: very true the string line is actual line of the file, and posted was the example to create a regular expression. sorry for all.